# twitter4j result.nextquery() is giving results from the first page again

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I've created a twitter crawler that gets tweets and its associated data that belongs to certain hashtags. After running it for more than a day, it started giving my old data that already stored in my database. Now I have exactly 216,874 tweets that has #jesuischarlie hashtag. Sure I used 
    `QueryResult result=twitter.search(new Query("#jesuischarlie"));`
And sure then I have a do-while loop never exits until `result.nextQuery()==null`

My question is why the function `nextQuery()` doesn't just give me a null which means Twitter won't provide further tweets for this search? Why is it starting from all over again!?

Here is the full function I'm using

```
try {
             Query query = new Query("#jesuischarlie");
             query.setSince("2015-01-08");
             query.setCount(100);
             QueryResult result;
             do {
                 result = twitter.search(query);
                 List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
                 for (Status tweet : tweets) {
                     Twitter_loop_dao dao = new Twitter_loop_dao();
                    try {

                        dao.insertTwet(tweet);
                    } catch (SQLException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 }
                 Thread.sleep(15 * 1000);
             } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);
             System.exit(0);
         } catch (TwitterException te) {
             te.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
             System.exit(-1);
         }
```

Comment: have you tried `while (result.hasNext());` as an exit condition for your loop ?

Comment: btw: `(result.getRateLimitStatus().getRemaining()` you get the number of the remaining requests within your window and with `Thread.sleep(result.getRateLimitStatus().getSecondsUntilReset() * 1000);` you can wait until your window will be reset.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation a lot. Then it was my mistake not Twitter policy of limitation or so. @mmx73

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you using the wrong exit condition in your while loop. My code is working (for me).

```
do {
        try {
            result = twitter.search(query);
            List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
            List<MyObject> myObjects = tweets.parallelStream()
                    .map(tweet -> myTweetFunction(tweet))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            query = result.nextQuery();            
            checkRateLimit(result) 

        } catch (TwitterException e){
            // do what ever you want
        }
} while (result == null || result.hasNext());
```

the checkRateLimit function:

```
private void checkRateLimit(QueryResult result) {

    if (result.getRateLimitStatus().getRemaining() <= 0){
        try {
          Thread.sleep(result.getRateLimitStatus().getSecondsUntilReset() * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.